# Is Autohotkey able to perform sequential pastes?

Tags: autohotkey, copy-paste

Is it possible to create a script for the multiple successive pastes?

Example: I copy ten different words with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (10 times) and paste into my doc pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (10 times).

Comment: A literal answer would be: yes, it's possible. However, stackoverflow is for specific questions about the code you write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
loop,
{
position = 0
loop,
{
~^c::
if (a_index = 9){
position = 0
}
else
{
position := position + 1
}

ClipWait
var%position% := clipboard
return
}

::p1::
send, %var1%
return

::p2::
send, %var2%
return

::p3::
send, %var3%
return

::p4::
send, %var4%
return

::p5::
send, %var5%
return

::p6::
send, %var6%
return

::p7::
send, %var7%
return

::p8::
send, %var8%
return

::p9::
send, %var9%
return

::p10::
send, %var10%
return
}
```

save clipboard into var then input them where and how you like to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. I tried it = doesn't work. Maybe it didn't work because I didn't understand your last comment: "sav clipboard into var..."

Comment: Type p1 hit space to paste first copied type p2 hit space   to paste second and so on .... p1 to p3

Comment: Ok, so what I did in Excel: copied 1, 2 and 3 cell. Open another tab and type p1 and press Space. And NOTHING!

Comment: How can be this answer the correct one if it does not use Ctrl+V at all? You said you wanted to copy 10 words (to a buffer i supose) and then paste them, not like this solution where you have to write a tag to obtain the value... At least modify your question or see the @ahkcoder solution for example

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
copiedText := []

~^C::
    ClipWait, 0
    copiedText.push(clipboard), clipboard := ""
return

^V::sendInput % copiedText.length() ? copiedText.remove(1) : _
```